Is Shemini Atzeret supposed to have a connection to the conquest?
There are parallels between entering Eretz Yisrael and shemini atzeret.
The Jewish people lives in tents, surrounded by clouds of glory. Then they circled Jericho seven times, and then sacked the city and acquired land for Israel.
Sukkot commemorates the booths/clouds, contains seven days of circling, and on shemini atzeret we read about Joshua, who conquered Jericho. Furthermore, 70 animals are offered on Succot "on behalf" of the nations and then SA is for the Jews relationship with God.
Is commemorating the conquest of Eretz Yisrael an official part of Shemini Atzeret or are these parallels not recognized?

I have not heard this connection though this isn't proof it doesn't exist. There is a well known medrash (I don't recall where precisely) about shemini started being one more day for the king to celebrate the jury with his children while the days of sukos focused on the entire kingdom (being a moshel for the other nations as reflected by the sacrifices)
